# Authentication for DocuSign PUT request fails in Postman

Tags: postman, docusignapi

Can anyone please help me with this DocuSign api authorization problem on Postman.
I am testing DocuSign api for updating Bulk recipients onto a template. 
The Url for api is

`PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/recipients/{recipientId}/bulk_recipients`.

the requestbody is

```
    {
        "bulkRecipients": [
        {
             "rowNumber": "1",
              "email": "nshi@xyz.towson.edu",
              "name": "Tracy",
              "tabLabels": [
               {
                   "name":"DepartmentText",
                   "value":"OTS"
               }
        ]
   }
```

I am using the same environment as the one for POST and Get request.
for testing on Postman.But I am getting authorization failed error.I have checked my integrator key.Its still the sam.It works for my GET and POST request of envelope creation and template .But it fails for this PUT request.Please tell me where I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There's no POST for this API, there's only GET/PUT/DELETE. 
you can see this here:
https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Authentication&tags=Authentication&operations=login&mode=basic